# Grab remaining text after last "/" in a php string

Tags: php, string

So, lets say I have a `$somestring` thats holds the value "main/physician/physician_view".

I want to grab just "physician_view".  I want it to also work if the passed string was "main/physician_view" or "site/main/physician/physician_view".

Hopefully my question makes sense.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You might find [`s($somestring)->afterLast('/')`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L445) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. I would probably use:

```php
$parts = explode('/', $string);
$last = array_pop($parts);
```

Comment: `explode` this: `str_repeat('/', 1337 * 1337);`

Comment: This throws a warning because `array_pop()` expects the parameter to be passed by reference, which is not possible for a function return value (the return value of `explode`). To avoid the warning you could say `&explode` but only until PHP 5.4. Otherwise, store the exploded string to a variable, and pass that by reference to `array_pop()`.

Comment: or, use "end" instead of "array_pop".
May be less overhead due to less array processing (i.e., removal of the last element from the array and retaining the reminder array set).

(curious about, which is faster and uses less resources - array_pop, end, or substr).

Comment: Or use a `@`:  `@array_pop(explode('/', $string));` 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Answer (score 83):

You can use [`strrpos()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) to find the last occurence of one string in another:

```
substr($somestring, strrpos($somestring, '/') + 1)
```

---

And if you don't know it always contains a slash, make it:

```
substr($somestring, strrpos("/$somestring", '/'))
```

For: PHP 7, PHP 8.

```
(string) substr($somestring, strrpos("/$somestring", '/'))
```

For: PHP 4, PHP 5.

https://3v4l.org/Oa9fq / https://3v4l.org/utXvS

---

This code does not have the issue of basename() that behaves differently depending on operating system (WIN16/32/64 DOS compatibility "\" and "/" vs. POSIX "/" only). If that is what you actually need, use basename().

https://php.net/basename

Comment: Doesn't always work. `path_without_slash` returns `ath_without_slash`, and if the slash is at the end, like `path/to/file/` it returns `(bool)false`

Comment: @BadHorsie: `(bool)false` from substr() requires (string)false for PHP 4,5, that could have eventually been known. Also your new 2012 requirement to handle strings without a slash I addressed now with an edit of the answer as it works exactly as it had been originally answered, the + 1 is only at a different place. Compare with your answer.

Answer (score 41):

Use [`basename`](http://php.net/basename), which was created for this exact purpose.

Comment: +1, Humm... Nice, but also removes "\" (at least on Windows). Does what the OP wants but a little bit more than the title of the question asks.

Comment: Use `basename` for that condition is a the best way to do this. Hello from 2k20

Answer (score 22):

```
$last_part = substr(strrchr($somestring, "/"), 1);
```

Examples:

```
php > $a = "main/physician/physician_view";
php > $b = "main/physician_view";
php > $c = "site/main/physician/physician_view";
php > echo substr(strrchr($a, "/"), 1);
    physician_view
php > echo substr(strrchr($b, "/"), 1);
    physician_view
php > echo substr(strrchr($c, "/"), 1);
    physician_view
```

Answer (score 4):

For another one liner, you can use the explode trick and reverse the array:

```
current(array_reverse(explode('/',$url)));
```

Answer (score 2):

The other solutions don't always work, or are inefficient. Here is a more useful general utility function that always works, and can be used with other search terms.

```
/**
 * Get a substring starting from the last occurrence of a character/string
 *
 * @param  string $str The subject string
 * @param  string $last Search the subject for this string, and start the substring after the last occurrence of it.
 * @return string A substring from the last occurrence of $startAfter, to the end of the subject string.  If $startAfter is not present in the subject, the subject is returned whole.
 */
function substrAfter($str, $last) {
    $startPos = strrpos($str, $last);
    if ($startPos !== false) {
        $startPos++;
        return ($startPos < strlen($str)) ? substr($str, $startPos) : '';
    }
    return $str;
}


// Examples

substrAfter('main/physician/physician_view', '/');  // 'physician_view'

substrAfter('main/physician/physician_view/', '/'); // '' (empty string)

substrAfter('main_physician_physician_view', '/');  // 'main_physician_physician_view'
```

Answer (score 2):

May be Late...

The Easiest way inbuilt in PHP to grab the last string after last `/` could be by simply using the `pathinfo` function.

In fact, you could check this for yourself,

```
$urlString = 'path/to/my/xximage.png';

$info = pathinfo($urlString);
```

You could do:

```
var_dump($info);
```

this will give you something like:

```
'dirname' => string 'path/to/my/' 
'basename' => string 'xximage.png'
'extension' => string 'png' (length=3)
'filename' => string 'xximage'
```

so to extract the images out of that link you could do:

```
 $img=$info['basename'];
 $extension=$info['extension'];
 ///etc...

echo $img.".".$extension; //xximage.png
```

Something small, but can make you Grow_Gray_Hair_Prematurely