# Pulling out a numeric value from the end of an SEO-friendly URL

Tags: php, str-replace

I need to take a unique parameter from url generally appendened as last word of the url.

For example, I need to take `2220193` and `2220136` from the following urls:

- "http://www.break.com/index/strange-sea-creature-retreats-into-ocean-floor-**2220193**"
- "http://www.break.com/index/bully-picks-fight-with-sleeping-inmate-**2220136**"

Generally I use `str_replace` to remove the static parameter "http://www.break.com/index/", but I don't know how to delete the textual url and get only the number.

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/strings

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150559/regular-expression-to-collect-everything-after-the-last and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762778/grab-remaining-text-after-last-in-a-php-string and countless others. please do research before asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = substr($url, strrpos($url, '-') + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use explode on the url, this returns a string array. The last value in the string array should contain what you are looking for.

Given that $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] would contain a url of the given format, you could use.

```
$url = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
$urlParts = explode($url, '-');

echo end($urlParts);
```

Comment: thanks, this will delete just (-) or all the "strange-sea-creature-retreats-into-ocean-floor", and this code can be used dinamically or just for the first url?

Answer (score 0):

Probably You could use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php) PHP function

Answer (score -1):

```
$outarr = explode('-',$inputstr);
$outnum = $outarr[count($outarr);
```