# Remove Characters After the Final '-' From String in PHP

Tags: php, string, substr

I have a script that processes filenames of the current file and converts them into Titles.

e.g. morse-1.1.1.php converts into "Morse" using the folowing:

```
<?php
function pageInfo($type) {
    $http = "http://";
    $server = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
    $filePath = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    $fileName = basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);

    // creating version by removing letters up to dash
    $position = strpos($fileName, '-');
    $version = str_replace(".php", "", $fileName);

    switch ($type) {
        case "title":
            $title = ucwords(substr($fileName, 0, $position));
            return $title;
            break;
        case "version":
            $numVersion = substr($version, $position+1);
            return "Version ".$numVersion;
            break;
        case "url":
            return $http.$server.$fileName;
            break;
    }

}

echo pageInfo("title");
?>
```

My issue is that I would like to use the same script when on the page "caeser-shift-2.1.php", but currently my function only finds the first '-' and removes characters based on that.
How do I adapt my function so that I remove the characters from the LAST '-' in the file name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grab remaining text after last "/" in a php string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762778/grab-remaining-text-after-last-in-a-php-string)

Answer (score 0):

Use [strrpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) function instead of strpos.

```
$position = strrpos($fileName, '-');
```

Comment: Thank you, such a simple solution - lack of string manipulation knowledge in php on my part

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "some-test-texts-crop;
$data = substr($str , 0 , strrpos($str ,"-") )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a short regex:

```
(.*)-.*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/xR1sF1/1

PHP:

```
echo preg_replace('~(.*)-.*~', '$1', 'caeser-shift-2.1.php');
```

Output:

> caeser-shift